# Как задать тегу ID особого вида через JS?

Tags: javascript

Как можно задать тегам подобный возрастающий id?

Из данного:

```
<h2>Заголовок</h2>
<h2>Заголовок</h2>
<h2>Заголовок</h2>
<h2>Заголовок</h2>
```

Сделать подобным образом:

```
<h2 id="count-1">Заголовок</h2>
<h2 id="count-2">Заголовок</h2>
<h2 id="count-3">Заголовок</h2>
<h2 id="count-4">Заголовок</h2>
```

Количество заголовков на странице может быть самым разным. Необходимо найти первый `<h2>` по DOM-структуре и к последующим прибавлять по 1. Получается, что необходимо указать какой-то цикл, наподобие как `for` в PHP, но как сделать подобное в JS не могу придумать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('h2').forEach((item, index) => item.id = "count-" + (index + 1));

document.querySelectorAll('h2').forEach(item => console.log(item.outerHTML));
```

```html
<h2>Заголовок</h2>
<h2>Заголовок</h2>
<h2>Заголовок</h2>
<h2>Заголовок</h2>
```

Comment: Igor, Богоподобно!

Comment: @QuickBrownFox Ну что Вы!...

Answer (score 3):

Ответ который дал Igor хорош, только этот код не будет работать в старых браузерах. Во первых стрелочные функции это фичи ES6, а главное метод forEach для NodeList начал поддерживаться не так давно. Что бы все работало везде лучше сделать как то так:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('h2')).forEach(function(item, index) { 
    item.id = "count-" + (index + 1) 
});
```